# How to check if a Postgres JSONArray has a string

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have  a Postgres table called pricing_rule that has a column called items of type json that saves records as a JSON Array example

```
[{"item_code":"Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC)","name":"5e0648a9e5","uom":null},{"item_code":"Dove Men Box (6.0 Box)","name":"d805f9bb9d","uom":null}]
```

How should I find the items whose item_code = 'Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC)' I came up with this:

```
select items->>'item_code' from pricing_rule where item_code->'Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC)';
```

but the `item_code` is not getting recognised. Anyhelp is appreciated.

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the contains operator `@>` to find the rows that contain that item code:

```
where items @> '[{"item_code": "Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC)"}]
```

If you also want to extract the matching array element, you can use a JSON path expression:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(items, '$[*] ? (@.item_code == "Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC)")')
from pricing_rule
where items @> '[{"item_code": "Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC)"}]
```

This assumes that `items` is a `jsonb` column (which it really should be). If it's not you need to cast it: `items::jsonb @> ...`

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name what should be here `jsonb_path_query_first` am a bit lost